# normalizing a matrix of vectors given magnitudes

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization

Given an (n x 3) matrix of n row vectors of the form (x,y,z) and a (n x 1) matrix  of the corresponding magnitudes of these vectors, how can I generate an (n x 3) matrix of the corresponding n column unit vectors **without** looping over n.

I've tried to illustrate this below:

given:

`[x1 y2 z1; 
  x2 y2 z2;
      ...
  xn yn zn]`

and

`[norm(x1 y1 z1)
 norm(x2 y2 z2)
      ....
 norm(xn yn zn)]`

how can i generate an (n x 3) matrix of the corresponsing unit column vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `matrix1` as the `nx3` input array, if you already have that magnitude vector `matrix2`, you can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) like so -

```
bsxfun(@rdivide,matrix1,matrix2(:))
```

If you need to calculate the magnitude vector too, you can do all of that in one go, like so -

```
bsxfun(@rdivide,matrix1,sqrt(sum(matrix1.^2,2)))
```

Comment: nice thanks! I got the magnitude part but didn't know about this magical bsxfunction!